# Interesting mysql 5.6 behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have this short snippet of code

```
SELECT candidate.ID 
FROM users u 
JOIN users candidate ON candidate.a = u.a AND candidate.b < 1
JOIN user_meta meta ON candidate.id = meta.user_id 
WHERE u.id = 1 
AND candidate.count > 0 
ORDER BY meta.updated_at DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

And it finishes in around 8s which I think is far to slow so I started to investigate a bit. I tried experiment with the join conditions

```
SELECT candidate.ID 
FROM users u 
JOIN users candidate ON candidate.a = u.a AND candidate.b < 2
JOIN user_meta meta ON candidate.id = meta.user_id 
WHERE u.id = 1 
AND candidate.count > 0 
ORDER BY meta.updated_at DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

and interesting enough this finishes in ~80ms. The only thing changed is the less than 1 to a less than 2.

Running EXPLAIN on the query yields the following for both queries

```
id select_type table       type   possible_keys   key                      key_len ref             rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      u           const  PRIMARY,index_a PRIMARY                  4        const           1    NULL
1  SIMPLE      meta        index  PRIMARY         index_meta_on_updated_at 5       NULL            100  Using index
1  SIMPLE      candidate   eq_ref PRIMARY,index_a PRIMARY                  4        db.meta.user_id 1    Using where
```

Probably something I have missed but what can cause this behavior?

Comment: How many records are there for `candidate.b < 1` and how many are there for `candidate.b < 2`? Do a separate query to find out. You can also use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and [SHOW _PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) to get detailed info on what MySQL does behind the scenes. `SHOW PROFILE` will give you detailed info and time on each step that MySQL performs to perform a query (opening tables, searching the index or disk, sending via network etc.)

Comment: if you are using innodb it could be that the table(s) are in the  innodb buffer (RAM memory) because you executed the first query. Could make sense why the second query is executing faster..

Comment: In regards to @RaymondNijland comment, I always use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to try and help compare apples to apples when investigating "problems" like this - but it won't help with the Innodb buffers.

Comment: Apart from the reasons for why the queries could behave that way (which has already been answered): You should add an index `user_meta(user_id, updated_at)`. This should bring down execution time significantly. If `users.a` has a foreign key to `users.id`, you also do not need to have `users` twice in your query (so you do not need the first `FROM users u`) - although it will only have a minor effect, as MySQL is already optimizing it away.

Comment: There are 1.5 times more records returned for `candidate.b < 2` than `candidate.b < 1`. Profiling shows bulk part spent in 'Sending data''. Added index to `candidate.b` and `candidate.count` did not help. Everything fits into memory. Somehow the `< 1` query shuffles a lot of more data even though it feels like it should be less.

Comment: @capitrane I think your comment would be good as a clarifying edit to the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information about:
 - The table ( you can use describe )
 - How many records has every table
 - Does the tables has index ?

For troubleshooting you can use in MySQL the explain extended like Mjh told you. Provide us the explain for every query this will help us give you a better advice or even help you to make your query better.

Comment: This is appropriate (and helpful) as a comment on the question, but not as an answer.  I'd move it there.

Comment: Since i can not add a comment i was forced to place it as an question.@wally

Comment: Ah, yes, apologies - I always forget SO forces that.  (It's been a long time since it affected me.)  To be honest, it feels like SO penalises new users, but I guess there has to be a tradeoff somewhere!